# is it possible to store the first pageX value on a touchstart?

Tags: javascript, touch, touchstart

I want to calculate the distance between the initial value of the touchstart and the actual value on touchmove.

for exemple :

I touch the screen : startX = 100;
Then, I move my finger on the screen : moveX = 150;

The distance from startX and moveX is (moveX - startX) = 50;

CODE UPDATED :

```
function touch(event) {
var moveX = event.pageX;
var totalMoved = Math.abs(document.startX - moveX);
shipX = totalMoved;
consoleLog(totalMoved);
};

function touchStart(event) {
    touch(event.touches[0]);
    document.startX = event.pageX;
};

function touchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    touch(event.touches[0]);
}; 

function touchEnd(event) {
    touch(event.touches[0]);
    var totalMoved = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You just need to store the value in a scope that will be visible in your `touchMove()` function.  For the sake of illustration, we can solve this problem by polluting the global scope:

```
function touchStart(event) {
    touch(event.touches[0]);
    window.startX = event.pageX;
};

function touchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var moveX = event.pageX;
    var totalMoved = Math.abs(window.startX - moveX);
};
```

Of course, there are various ways to do this without polluting the global scope.  For instance, you could make your event handler functions be members of some object that holds the necessary state as member variables.  Or the `touchStart()` handler could create a closure that encapsulates the `startX` variable and then set that to be the `touchesMoved` handler.  And so on.

Comment: thanks now the startX value is correct, but I need to reset it on touchend, I know that can't change totalmoved in a different function than touch(); but I can't see how to do it otherwise. (See my updated code)

Answer (score 0):

You `moveX`s are declared in different functions and hence denote different variables. Declare `var moveX` in the enclosing scope for all these functions instead (I guess you might want to do the same with `startX`).